# mysql left join and query with where in clause showing only 1 row

Tags: mysql, left-join

As i am making a simple forum with the touch of twitter like follower and following, i have following tables.

```
users

 1. id
 2. name

questions

 1. id
 2. description
 3. user_id//foreign key of users.id

answers

 1. id
 2. question_id//foreign key of questions.id
 3. description
 4. user_id//foreign key of users.id

follow

 1. from_user(which user)//foreign key of users.id
 2. to_user(following to which user)//foreign key of users.id
```

My query is as follow

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, count(DISTINCT questions.id), count(answers questions.id), count(follow1.from_user), count(follow2.to_user) from users LEFT JOIN questions ON users.id = questions.user_id LEFT JOIN answers ON users.id = answers.user_id LEFT JOIN follow as follow1 ON users.id = follow1.from_user LEFT JOIN follow as follow2 ON users.id = follow2.to_user WHERE users.id = 1
```

This works fine and give the proper result.

But when with the same query i put the clause of WHERE IN as follows

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, count(DISTINCT questions.id), count(answers questions.id), count(follow1.from_user), count(follow2.to_user) from users LEFT JOIN questions ON users.id = questions.user_id LEFT JOIN answers ON users.id = answers.user_id LEFT JOIN follow as follow1 ON users.id = follow1.from_user LEFT JOIN follow as follow2 ON users.id = follow2.to_user WHERE users.id IN (1, 3)
```

It shows the record only for user id 1. Not for 3. But talking about the previous query works fine for both `id's` and show the proper records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an odd one, i can only suggest using `GROUP BY users.id` so that mysql doesn't combine the count()s over all records. Hope that in some way helps.

Comment: oh my my my..! this is really kind of worst. because approx 1 year ago i knew that and now i forget it. I don't know what to tell myself. Anyways thanks a lot. I am really disappointed with myself.

Comment: :D fresh(ish) eyes looking at a problem is all that is.